# what does two slashes in jQuery mean

Tags: jquery, syntax

Could someone explain this line of jQuery? I'm not sure what the slashes mean:

```
var age=$('#main\\:mainForm\\:months').val();
```

Comment: thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as they're backslashes, the first backslash escapes the second backslash, so the actual contents of the string evaluates to:

```
#main\:mainForm\:months
```

The `:` character has special meaning in selections. It allows for custom expressions such as `:nth-child()`. using the `\` character to escape the `:` allows you to select an element with an `[id]` attribute of `#main:mainForm:months`

Answer (score 10):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`.

Answer (score 2):

It's the escape character, so it means to use the literal `:` value, so look for an element with `id="main:mainForm:months"`

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more information